# Three.js CanvasRenderer, having problems setting an image texture to a plane

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, three.js

So basically, I'm attempting to emulate a UI sort of like those used in Halo Reach menus. I plan on going about this by setting the background of the webpage to some image, creating a plane in front of it, and setting its texture to an image with some semi-transparent rectangle shapes on it to be used as the main background of the UI itself. I'll worry about the buttons and what not in the future, but as of now I can no longer get it to render anything on the canvas. Previously it was able to render the plane in the correct spot with a white material, but at some point while attempting to apply a texture to it I managed to mix something up and as a result it doesn't render anything.

Here is a link to the source if anyone is able to help me:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/40043006/test.zip\

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're hitting [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally). However, I would suggest using plain HTML/images for UI stuff.

Comment: Oh wow! That would do it, thank you very much for finding that!